# Is there a preferred way to name variables in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

I am fairly new to PHP and I was wondering if there was a standard convention to name php variables.  I'm used to using camel case when naming variables, but I see a lot of underscores in PHP examples.

Is there a standard naming convention that most people use for PHP?

`$buildingHeight` OR `$building_height`

Comment: a consistent approach is more important than what style you choose. OR "no, there is no preferred way" there are only different conventions that are followed. Incidentally asking _if_ there is a standard isn't off topic IMO wheras asking for preference (which is how some are going to interpret this question) _is_ off topic.

Comment: no there isn't standard but when I do use variables I prefer camel case naming variables.

Comment: The only thing you need to do is put a $ in front of it :P
I personally prefer camelcase.

Comment: Find a [coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and stick to it.

Comment: Is this opinion-based because it's not mentioned in PSR-2? If the question had been about method names, this would not be opinion-based, because it's mentioned in PSR-2 and the decision comes from a vote, right? So why isn't a valid answer to this something like "it isn't mentioned in PSR-2, so no."

Comment: I don't think this question is opinion-based. As @AD7six says, OP is asking _if_ a standard exists, not what people prefer to use.

Comment: @MikeB PSR-1 says: "This guide intentionally avoids any recommendation regarding the use of $StudlyCaps, $camelCase, or $under_score property names." This is as close as it gets to mentioning variable names, so it's not really useful to recommend "sticking to it" in this case, is it?

Comment: @DaggNabbit Interesting, it used to be defined https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/pull/14#discussion-diff-486508R14. I guess they couldn't get all the frameworks to agree on one.

Comment: @MikeB, interesting discussion there, helps explain why nothing could be decided on.

Comment: @DaggNabbit either way though, PSR-* are not authoriative PHP standards and don't apply to php as a whole - only to any project/code that chooses to adopt it as their code standard/style guide. As such referring to PSR as definitive _would be_ opinionated, since it's perfectly valid to contradict them.

Comment: @AD7six OP never asked for a *definitive* or *authoritative* standard, only a standard that "most people use," which I chose to interpret as "many people use" (I'm thinking about making that edit, in fact). A style guideline for the PHP language itself wouldn't be relevant here (or anywhere given the state of PHP); I think it's pretty clear that OP wants a standard to apply to projects written in PHP.

Comment: @DaggNabbit That question is itself subjective, the title isn't though. I'm only pointing out why [your own comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858756/is-there-a-preferred-way-to-name-variables-in-php?noredirect=1#comment31292624_20858756) would be considered opinion based, even if about method names. There are multiple standards that "many people use", there is no majority. The answer to this question is "No" (or "No, But [some objective info]", not all of "Yes Pear" "Yes PSR" "Yes ..."

Comment: @AD7six it is not my *opinion* that a standard exists that covers (or doesn't cover) some naming convention, and I'm not offering my *opinion* that such a standard should or shouldn't be followed. If some standard exists that covers it, that's a fact, not an opinion. Simply pointing to a standard that covers this (or indicating that no existing standards cover it) doesn't seem to involve opinions at all if you ask me (and yes, I'm using the term "standard" loosely here).

Comment: @DaggNabbit you misinterpret what FIG standards are. emphasis added [**Our main audience is each other**, but we’re very aware that the rest of the PHP community is watching. **If other folks want to adopt what we’re doing they are welcome to do so, but that is not the aim**](http://www.php-fig.org/faq/)

Comment: @AD7six I'm not sure how that's relevant to the question of whether pointing to an existing "standard or whatever" that addresses this has anything to do with the answerer's *opinion*.

Comment: @AD7six, what I'm saying is that close reason exists to avoid opinionated *answers.* What you seem to be saying is that the spec itself is only someone's opinion, so an answer pointing to it is, by proxy, opinion. I'm saying it's not. The spec might be based on someone's opinion, but saying "there's a spec here that covers this" is a fact, not an opinion.

Comment: you misunderstand my comments and what FIG is - it is _not_ the standard for PHP. I am not saying FIG is someone's opinion I'm saying _it's not the standard for PHP_. As soon as you accept that, it should be clear that saying "Yes because ... fig" is opinion in the context of "Is there a preferred way to name variables in PHP?" -we've already gone on for too long - HNY.

Comment: @AD7six I have read this many times before and feel that I understand its intentions. Clearly it is not a standard for PHP, but it seems obvious that the intent is to propose a standard way of writing code for PHP projects. As such, I think it's exactly the sort of thing the OP probably had in mind, since nothing more official exists. I stand by my statement that simply pointing to a document (like PSR-2) that some number of people have agreed on and indicating that it covers some stylistic concern is not an *opinion*, and is probably the kind of answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: It's clear to me from this discussion that there is no official standard, thanks and I'm sorry if the question was a bit unclear.

Comment: [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/userlandnaming.rules.php) states that *internally* they follow this guideline: *"Function names use underscores between words, while class names use both the camelCase and PascalCase rules."* Of course, you may pick any convention you want for your own code. Some frameworks have a particular convention. The link also shows exceptions to their "rule" and additional rules they (try) to follow. They also indicate this [official rules link](https://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob_plain;f=CODING_STANDARDS.md;hb=HEAD). Note:`-` is NOT allowed.

Comment: While users are not required to follow these guidelines, [PHP official *internal* naming convention](https://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob_plain;f=CODING_STANDARDS.md;hb=HEAD), section *"## User functions/methods naming conventions"* states: 
*4. Variable names must be meaningful. One letter variable names must be avoided,
    except for places where the variable has no real meaning or a trivial
    meaning (e.g. `for (i=0; i<100; i++) ...`).

**5. Variable names should be in lowercase. Use underscores to separate between
    words.***

Comment: Meanwhile the same document also states: *3. Function names used by user functions should be prefixed with `_php_`, and
    followed by a word or an **underscore-delimited list of words, in lowercase**
    letters, that describes the function. If applicable, they should be declared
    `static`.* **camelCase Methods** *6. Method names follow the *studlyCaps* (also referred to as *bumpy case* or
   *camel caps*) naming convention, with care taken to minimize the letter
    count. The initial letter of the name is lowercase, and each letter that
    starts a new `word` is capitalized:*

Comment: Lastly, ***Class names** should be descriptive nouns in **PascalCase** and as short as
    possible. Each word in the class name should start with a capital letter,
    without underscore delimiters. The class name should be prefixed with the
    name of the "parent set" (e.g. the name of the extension) if no namespaces
    are used. Abbreviations and acronyms as well as initialisms should be
    avoided wherever possible, unless they are much more widely used than the
    long form (e.g. HTTP or URL). Abbreviations start with a capital letter
    followed by lowercase letters...*

Comment: This is the [PHP documentation page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/userlandnaming.rules.php) that lists the above link as the official *internal* PHP coding (and naming) standard: [ » CODING STANDARDS:](https://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob_plain;f=CODING_STANDARDS.md;hb=HEAD).

Answer (score 1):

It is really all about your preference in the case you mentioned. I prefer using underscore because it helps me read the variables better when scanning through the code, but ultimately it's up to you.

**Other important things to note about PHP variables:**

- Must start with a letter or underscore (_).
- May only be composed of alpha-numeric characters and underscores a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or _ .

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is not any standard naming, but on [PHP webpage](http://www.php.net/) all examples use camel case.

You should use your own favorite standard naming :)

Comment: Not true.  Internally, PHP uses an **underscore convention for variables and functions**, *camelCase for Methods*, and *PascaleCase for classes*, as per https://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob_plain;f=CODING_STANDARDS.md;hb=HEAD, which is linked to on this [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/userlandnaming.rules.php) page.  That said, these are conventions used by PHP itself, and are not required to be followed by anyone else.